# Redicionar após enviar formulário com react-router-dom?

Tags: react

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?

A situação é a seguinte, estou usando o react-router-dom numa aplicação em ReactJS e preciso que após clicar em salvar em um formulário, o mesmo vá para a tela de listagem, mostrando o novo registro. A principio com o { Link } do react-router-dom eu consigo redirecionar, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que seja atualizada a lista do CRUD.

Alguém saberia me ajudar com isso?

Agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente porque no redirecionamento com o uso do router o seu componente não está recebendo o state atualizado, então ao retornar para a listagem do crud você deverá adicionar algum método como o shouldComponentUpdate ou componentWillReceiveProps para fazer com que o componente de lista pegue o estado atual da sua aplicação. Lembrando, quando você faz a transição entre componentes via router o seu componente não é inicializado com a trilha toda (componentWillMount, componentDidMount e etc).